# How A Bundle can access OSGi output stream?

Tags: osgi, bundle

Is there any way for a bundle to print an string in OSGi output stream?
I mean like `System.out.println("String");`. Instead of this I want the bundle to print its strings in that stream.

```
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
    Activator.context = bundleContext;
    System.out.println("Hello World!"); // I want to print this string in osgi console.
}
```

You see, if I run the OSGi framework it will print its responses to commands in Java Console, where System.out prints as well.

But my problem is that, I'm printing its outputs in a JTextArea, so I want bundles to be able to print there too (Print its strings in OSGi Console output stream). in this case I need a way to access the OSGi output stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your JTextArea serves as a console or a view for the console output. So I'd suggest to just display the System.out stream in that JTextArea. Here's an example to achieve this: http://unserializableone.blogspot.com/2009/01/redirecting-systemout-and-systemerr-to.html

Comment: Yes you understood well. :) That's a good suggestion but it has a minor flaw. It will print the exception's too!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't understand the question. That will write to where ever System.out is directed. If you start an OSGi framework from the command line, that should write to the terminal session.

Comment: Unfortunately, It's pretty complicated to clear what I mean!

You see, if I run the OSGi framework it will print its responses to commands in Java Console, where System.out prints as well.

But my problem is that, I'm printing its outputs in a JTextArea, so I want bundles to be able to print there too.